# How to randomly select districts and villages in that district in R?

Tags: r, random, dplyr, sample

I have a data set containing information on district code and name, code and name of the blocks in that district, and the code and name of the villages that come in that block.

Based on this I want to create a data set that randomly selects a block from the district and randomly takes 10 villages in that selected block.

I have tried using the sample function and the RandomizeR package but could get it to work.

I sample of the data set (df):

```
structure(list(district_code = c(1701L, 1701L, 1701L, 1701L, 
1701L, 1701L, 1701L, 1701L, 1701L, 1701L, 1701L, 1701L), district_name = c("morena", 
"morena", "morena", "morena", "morena", "morena", "morena", "morena", 
"morena", "morena", "morena", "morena"), block_code = c(1701001L, 
1701001L, 1701001L, 1701001L, 1701001L, 1701001L, 1701001L, 1701001L, 
1701001L, 1701001L, 1701001L, 1701001L), block_name = c("ambah", 
"ambah", "ambah", "ambah", "ambah", "ambah", "ambah", "ambah", 
"ambah", "ambah", "ambah", "ambah"), village_code = 1701001001:1701001012, 
    village_name = c("badfara", "bichola", "bhandauli", "lallubasai", 
    "kakarari", "rithona", "goonjh", "malbasai", "aroli", "khirenta", 
    "dandoli", "beelpur")), row.names = c(NA, 12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Second sample (df1)

```
structure(list(district_code = c(3424L, 3424L, 3424L, 3424L, 
3424L, 3424L, 3424L, 3424L, 3401L, 3401L, 3401L, 3401L, 3401L, 
3402L, 3402L, 3402L, 3402L, 3402L, 3402L, 3402L, 3402L), district_name = c("khunti", 
"khunti", "khunti", "khunti", "khunti", "khunti", "khunti", "khunti", 
"ranchi", "ranchi", "ranchi", "ranchi", "ranchi", "lohardaga", 
"lohardaga", "lohardaga", "lohardaga", "lohardaga", "lohardaga", 
"lohardaga", "lohardaga"), block_code = c(3401020L, 3401020L, 
3401020L, 3401020L, 3401020L, 3401020L, 3401020L, 3401020L, 3401024L, 
3401024L, 3401024L, 3401024L, 3401024L, 3402001L, 3402001L, 3402001L, 
3402001L, 3402001L, 3402001L, 3402001L, 3402001L), block_name = c("torpa", 
"torpa", "torpa", "torpa", "torpa", "torpa", "torpa", "torpa", 
"khelari", "khelari", "khelari", "khelari", "khelari", "lohardaga", 
"lohardaga", "lohardaga", "lohardaga", "lohardaga", "lohardaga", 
"lohardaga", "lohardaga"), panchayat_code = c(3401020009, 3401020010, 
3401020011, 3401020012, 3401020013, 3401020014, 3401020015, 3401020016, 
3401024001, 3401024002, 3401024003, 3401024004, 3401024005, 3402001001, 
3402001002, 3402001003, 3402001004, 3402001005, 3402001006, 3402001007, 
3402001008), panchayat_name = c("marcha", "okra", "sundari", 
"tapkara", "torpa east", "torpa west", "ukrimari", "urikela", 
"churi east", "churi middle", "churi north", "churi south", "churi west", 
"hesal", "hirhi", "manho", "jori", "nigni", "juriya", "harmu", 
"rampur")), row.names = 379:399, class = "data.frame")
> dput(jk_subset[379:409,])
structure(list(district_code = c(3424L, 3424L, 3424L, 3424L, 
3424L, 3424L, 3424L, 3424L, 3401L, 3401L, 3401L, 3401L, 3401L, 
3402L, 3402L, 3402L, 3402L, 3402L, 3402L, 3402L, 3402L, 3402L, 
3402L, 3402L, 3402L, 3402L, 3402L, 3402L, 3402L, 3402L, 3402L
), district_name = c("khunti", "khunti", "khunti", "khunti", 
"khunti", "khunti", "khunti", "khunti", "ranchi", "ranchi", "ranchi", 
"ranchi", "ranchi", "lohardaga", "lohardaga", "lohardaga", "lohardaga", 
"lohardaga", "lohardaga", "lohardaga", "lohardaga", "lohardaga", 
"lohardaga", "lohardaga", "lohardaga", "lohardaga", "lohardaga", 
"lohardaga", "lohardaga", "lohardaga", "lohardaga"), block_code = c(3401020L, 
3401020L, 3401020L, 3401020L, 3401020L, 3401020L, 3401020L, 3401020L, 
3401024L, 3401024L, 3401024L, 3401024L, 3401024L, 3402001L, 3402001L, 
3402001L, 3402001L, 3402001L, 3402001L, 3402001L, 3402001L, 3402001L, 
3402001L, 3402001L, 3402006L, 3402001L, 3402007L, 3402007L, 3402007L, 
3402002L, 3402002L), block_name = c("torpa", "torpa", "torpa", 
"torpa", "torpa", "torpa", "torpa", "torpa", "khelari", "khelari", 
"khelari", "khelari", "khelari", "lohardaga", "lohardaga", "lohardaga", 
"lohardaga", "lohardaga", "lohardaga", "lohardaga", "lohardaga", 
"lohardaga", "lohardaga", "lohardaga", "kairo", "lohardaga", 
"peshrar", "peshrar", "peshrar", "kisko", "kisko"), village_code = c(3401020009, 
3401020010, 3401020011, 3401020012, 3401020013, 3401020014, 3401020015, 
3401020016, 3401024001, 3401024002, 3401024003, 3401024004, 3401024005, 
3402001001, 3402001002, 3402001003, 3402001004, 3402001005, 3402001006, 
3402001007, 3402001008, 3402001009, 3402001010, 3402001011, 3402001012, 
3402001013, 3402002001, 3402002002, 3402002003, 3402002004, 3402002005
), village_name = c("marcha", "okra", "sundari", "tapkara", 
"torpa east", "torpa west", "ukrimari", "urikela", "churi east", 
"churi middle", "churi north", "churi south", "churi west", "hesal", 
"hirhi", "manho", "jori", "nigni", "juriya", "harmu", "rampur", 
"bagha", "arkosa", "tigra", "guri", "bhatdhijri", "siram", "peshrar", 
"rorad", "devdaria", "pakhar")), row.names = 379:409, class = "data.frame")
```

Example of data set after using the code:

```
3404L, 3405L, 3406L, 3407L, 3408L, 3409L, 3410L, 3411L), district_name = c("khunti", 
"ranchi", "lohardaga", "gumla", "simdega", "palamu", "latehar", 
"garhwa", "west singhbhum", "saraikela kharsawan", "east singhbum", 
"dumka"), block_code = c(3401009L, 3401013L, 3402005L, 3403009L, 
3404002L, 3405018L, 3406006L, 3407009L, 3408005L, 3409006L, 3410005L, 
3411009L), block_name = c("khunti", "namkum", "bhandra", "basia", 
"bolba", "tarhasi", "garu", "bhandaria", "tantnagar", "ichagarh", 
"musabani", "masaliya"), village_code = c(3401009002, 3401013020, 
3402005002, 3403009008, 3404002002, 3405006012, 3406006008, 3407009002, 
3408005001, 3409006012, 3410005011, 3411009001), village_name = c("bhandra", 
"sithiyo", "bhandra", "mamarla", "kadopani", "manjhauli 2", "ghasitola", 
"bhandaria", "angardiha", "dewaltand", "ichra (north)", "aamgachi"
)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is not really suited to provide a solution since it only contains one district/block.

But you can do:

```
df %>%
  group_by(district_code) %>%
  filter(block_code == ifelse(length(unique(block_code)) == 1, block_code, sample(unique(block_code), size = 1))) %>%
  filter(village_code %in% ifelse(length(unique(village_code)) == 1, village_code, sample(unique(village_code), size = min(10, length(unique(village_code))), replace = FALSE))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Note: I wasn‘t entirely sure at which level you want to sample, so here I select one block per district and then 10 villages from that block. So you will end up with 10 villages from a randomly selected block for each district.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I wanted to know if the dataset contained some blocks with less than 10 villages. Will it be possible to include them in the command? I have tried the following but it does not work. ```df %>%
  group_by(district_code) %>%
  filter(block_code == sample(as.numeric(unique(block_code)), size = 1)) %>%
  filter(village_code %in% sample(as.numeric(unique(village_code)), size <= 10, replace = FALSE)) %>%
  ungroup()```

Comment: If a block contains less then 10 villages, my code should still work. It will just sample less than 10 elements then.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. I just couldn't figure out the limited values in the data set.

Comment: I updated my code to fix the issues from your other post.

Comment: For the other data set, I keep on running into an error. *Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
i Input `..1` is ``%in%`(...)`.
x object 'village_code' not found
i The error occurred in group 1: district_code = 3401.*  I have also added the second example to the question.

Comment: Isn‘t the error pretty clear? „Village_code not found“. If you look at your second data, isn‘t it immediately clear that you have panchayat_code instead? If you replace these things in the code, it should run fine.

Comment: Sorry about it, I am panicking and behaving like a clown. Your code worked but it is giving me only 1 block and 1 village per district. I have posted a copy in the question itself.

Comment: Yes. You get one block per district and one village/panchayat per block. This is clear and expected since you only have one unique village_code per block. So please clarify if you want to randomly sample 10 villages per block (no matter if the have the same village_code or not) or if you want to sample in a way that you select one village from up to 10 randomly chosen village_codes.

Comment: In easier terms: Let‘s assume you have 10 villages, 5 with cillage code „A“, 5 with village code „B“. If you say „I want to sample one village“, does that mean you want to just randomly select one of the 10 villages or does it mean you want to randomly select one village code (so either A or B) and then select all 5 villages from that village code?

Comment: I want to randomly sample 10 villages per block. However, in some blocks there are less than 10 villages and I want to take all of them. I have tried <=10 but it gives the error occupied in group 1: district_code=301 with respect to the second data set

Comment: And regarding the blocks you wanted to randomly sample one of the blocks, right?  So overall, you habe districts, and we sample one block in each district. And then in each block we randomly sample 10 villages?