# X cannot take a sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE' with respect to District Codes

Tags: r, dplyr, sample

I am randomly selecting a block from a district. Then from the block, I am randomly selecting 10 villages. I had some issues with the code which was duly solved. I replicated the code to other data frames. However, in 2 particular data sets, I am facing a common. I am posting the code, the error, and the sample dataset.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could explain to me the meaning of the error as well.

The code:

```
df<- jk_subset %>%
  group_by(district_code) %>%
  filter(block_code == sample(as.numeric(unique(block_code)), size = 1)) %>%
  filter(village_code %in% sample(as.numeric(unique(village_code)), size= 10, replace = FALSE)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

The error:

*Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
i Input `..1` is ``%in%`(...)`.
x cannot take a sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE'
i The error occurred in group 2: district_code = 3402.*

The sample data set:

```
structure(list(district_code = c(3424L, 3424L, 3424L, 3424L, 
3424L, 3424L, 3424L, 3424L, 3401L, 3401L, 3401L, 3401L, 3401L, 
3402L, 3402L, 3402L, 3402L, 3402L, 3402L, 3402L, 3402L), district_name = c("khunti", 
"khunti", "khunti", "khunti", "khunti", "khunti", "khunti", "khunti", 
"ranchi", "ranchi", "ranchi", "ranchi", "ranchi", "lohardaga", 
"lohardaga", "lohardaga", "lohardaga", "lohardaga", "lohardaga", 
"lohardaga", "lohardaga"), block_code = c(3401020L, 3401020L, 
3401020L, 3401020L, 3401020L, 3401020L, 3401020L, 3401020L, 3401024L, 
3401024L, 3401024L, 3401024L, 3401024L, 3402001L, 3402001L, 3402001L, 
3402001L, 3402001L, 3402001L, 3402001L, 3402001L), block_name = c("torpa", 
"torpa", "torpa", "torpa", "torpa", "torpa", "torpa", "torpa", 
"khelari", "khelari", "khelari", "khelari", "khelari", "lohardaga", 
"lohardaga", "lohardaga", "lohardaga", "lohardaga", "lohardaga", 
"lohardaga", "lohardaga"), village_code = c(3401020009, 3401020010, 
3401020011, 3401020012, 3401020013, 3401020014, 3401020015, 3401020016, 
3401024001, 3401024002, 3401024003, 3401024004, 3401024005, 3402001001, 
3402001002, 3402001003, 3402001004, 3402001005, 3402001006, 3402001007, 
3402001008), village_name = c("marcha", "okra", "sundari", 
"tapkara", "torpa east", "torpa west", "ukrimari", "urikela", 
"churi east", "churi middle", "churi north", "churi south", "churi west", 
"hesal", "hirhi", "manho", "jori", "nigni", "juriya", "harmu", 
"rampur")), row.names = 379:399, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You don't have a `village_code` variable in your sample, the code throws a different error.

Comment: And the error you get can be understand as the fact that there is less than 10 village in your second group, so you cannot sample 10 villages.

Comment: @Maël sorry there was an error on my part, I have added village_code to the example. There are more than 10 villages in the second group. I didn't show them otherwise the sample would have become very big.

Comment: If there are more than 10 villages per group, then this error won't show up. It must something else but we can't reproduce the error with the sample.

Comment: Also. It would be more appropriate to post this issue as a comment in your original question, so that the solution I provided there could potentially be fixed.

Comment: I suggest to continue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71261856/how-to-randomly-select-districts-and-villages-in-that-district-in-r/71262034?noredirect=1#comment125971410_71262034

Comment: I updated my answer in this other question so that it should not return an error anymore.